# Is it possible to detach the terminal window from VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I really like using the VSCode terminal and I don't want to fire up a separate terminal app, but the integrated terminal occupies too much screen space. It would be great to move it to another monitor or reposition it. Is this possible?

Comment: same thoughts here... ?did you found a solution?? :-)

Comment: related on SO: [Is it possible to open integrated terminals from VS Code in a separate window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59665958/11107541)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to open the integrated terminal (or anything in the panel) in a new window directly. If you do not want to use an external terminal you could:

- make the terminal its' smallest possible size and maximize it using the "^" button ([Image of the ^ button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvKhl.png)) on demand. You can also set a shortcut for `workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel` to achieve this more efficiently.
- create a new VSCode Window and only work with the panel / integrated terminal in the new window.

[Note: This answer is outdated. Now this is directly possible. See the following answers, including hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> ]

Comment: Ah! Yes I liked your 2nd point. I should have thought of that. Thanks Tom

Comment: Of course, you can't use the same folder/workspace... You'll have to open a folder further up or down lolz.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest to simply not to use the built in terminal, but open a standalone one out of VS Code.
You can use any terminal you want.

[image: VS Code and standalone Powershell]

Comment: how is this accomplished?  Is there a setting that needs to be set?

Comment: You just need to open a new terminal (not on vscode)  and go to the same folder as your vscode workspace

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Problem is you can't run e.g. VSCode Tasks or Launches this way. Using a new VSCode window seems to be the only way.

Comment: It's not the same, the pane with terminal also contains `problems`, `output`, `debug console` etc. These require the workspace context.

Comment: This is not a valid answer. The OP clearly states "I don't want to fire up a separate terminal app". There could be multiple good reasons for this so let's not make assumptions and just try to answer the question.

Answer (score 7):

Detached windows using the same workspace is not supported yet in Visual Studio Code. The highly upvoted feature request is at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10121.

Comment: It's locked for support and has got no updates since 2019 

Comment: Apparently, support for floating windows has landed in the latest version, but as of yet, I can't find a way to make the terminal float in its own window. (There's no 'Move into New Window command in the terminal's context menu as there is for editor tabs.)

Answer (score 6):

Since VsCode is kind of a electron application, its UI is a webpage rendered inside embedded chromium browser. See for yourself:  Open menu Help / Toggle Developer tools.

So you're basically asking if you can pop out DIV of a web page and "open" it in another browser instance. This is not possible.

Comment: Electron can open multiple browser windows from the same app.  See, for example, Obsidian.

Answer (score 5):

As several buried answers have pointed out, this is possible now. Here's how, with screenshots:

[[image: Screenshot showing VSCode context menu option "Move Terminal Into Editor Area".]]

Click on the terminal name in the side panel and select "Move Terminal Into Editor Area". This will move the terminal into a new editor tab.

[[image: Screenshot showing VSCode context menu option "Move Terminal Into Editor Area", with multiple terminals open.]]

If you have multiple terminals open, you'll need to right click on it in the list of open terminals instead.

[[image: Screenshot showing VsCode context menu option "Move Into New Window".]]

Right click on the newly-created terminal tab and select "Move Into New Window".

Answer (score 1):

I managed to accomplish this with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd>

I found this on the following list of keyboard shortcuts:

https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

Comment: When pressing `Ctrl + k o` i get an error:
> The active editor must contain an openable resource.

Comment: This is for editor windows AFAICT - not terminals

Comment: What you have seen is Ctrl k + ctrl 0 (not o) and this shortcut is nothing to do with the terminal, it's for code folding.

Answer (score 1):

We can now do it with the latest version of vscode. It is currently a two step process:

1. Move the terminal into the editor area
2. Drag the tab out to its own window

Demo: https://twitter.com/i/status/1733176182982541662

Answer (score 0):

A popout window would be nice.

But you CAN absolutely get the terminal window onto a "second monitor":

1. Resize vscode by corner-dragging so its windows extends across 2 screens - Generally extending to the right.
2. Set your terminal window to be on the right. (Right-click the terminal/output tabs section)
3. Then move the split point to be just at the join of your monitors.

TaDa! - Terminal window now 'by itself' on your monitor on the right.

I work like this daily...

Comment: ... if they're the same size, resolution and DPI.

Comment: @AshleyWilson - I suppose your mileage could vary with differing monitor parameters, sure. But my two monitors vary by both size and physical DPI and it works fine. At my work the right-hand monitor is in portrait, and it works fine... If you don't like the way the terminal looks on the secondary monitor, adjust the terminal font in vscode perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The ideal case of what you're asking for is tracked by two issue tickets that are still open (not implemented):

- [Extract the integrated terminal #34442](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34442)
- [Allow for floating windows
  #10121](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10121) (a more general request covering all Panels)

You can give those issue tickets a thumbs up reaction to show support for them getting implemented, and subscribe to them to get notified about discussions and updates. <sup><sub>[But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

As for workarounds, you can create a new and empty VS Code window (with no workspace folder), and drag the terminal from your pre-existing window into that one. You can also detach the session from one VS Code window, and then reattach it into another one (using the `Terminal: Detach Session` and `Terminal: Attach to Session` commands in the command palette respectively). See also the [user docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/advanced#_moving-terminals-between-windows).

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.84 it's been possible to move the terminal into an editor area. And since in 1.85 you can also move editors into new windows, it's now possible to move the terminal into its own standalone window. See [the update log](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85#_floating-editor-windows):

> We are happy to announce that with this release you can move editors out of the main window into their own lightweight windows. Changes to an editor in one window apply immediately to all other windows where the editor is open.
> The easiest way to create a floating editor window is to drag an editor out of the current window and drop it on an empty space on your desktop.
> ...
> And since both terminals and search results can be opened as editors, you can now have these features in separate windows as well!